# Is there one more bug of the gcc compiler relative to inherited constructors?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++17, inherited-constructors

This code does not compile using gcc HEAD 10.0.0 20190 but compiles using clang HEAD 9.0.0

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A( int ) {}
};

struct B
{
    B() = default;
    B( const char * ) {}
};

template <typename...Bases>
struct C : Bases...
{
    using Bases::Bases...;
};

int main()
{
}
```

The error is

```
rog.cc:18:23: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
   18 |     using Bases::Bases...;
      |                       ^~~
prog.cc:18:23: note:         'Bases'
```

Comment: And the error is.....

Comment: Isn't that this bug [Bug 79094 - Pack expansion in using-declaration rejects an attempt to inherit a pack of constructors](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79094)?

Comment: @t.niese Oh, yes. Write your answer and I will close the question.

Comment: I don't know if the code is valid or not, so I don't know what to write as an answer. I only know that it exists as Issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expansions are only allowed in *using-declarations* since C++17. ([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack))

Looks like your GCC version just doesn't have that new feature yet, or does but in a buggy way (e.g. [bug 79094](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79094)).